# MLFlow installation error, "AttributeError: 'EntryPoints' object has no attribute 'get'"

Tags: python, mlflow

Trying to install ML Flow on a fresh VM and getting into the error below.

VM Config: Windows Server 2022 Datacenter  21H2  20348.2113

Steps to Install MLFlow:
Installed Python 3.12.1

pip3 install mlflow

This resulted into the error "ModuleNoteFoundErrror: No module named 'pkg_resources'"
[image]

To fix this, installed "setuptools" -> pip3 install --upgrade setuptools
Now the error is **"AttributeError: 'EntryPoints' object has no attribute 'get'"** which I cannot get around.
[image]

There are number of posts regarding version compatibility but it is not helping. Below are the versions of libs.

```
mlflow==2.9.1
importlib-metadata==7.0.0
```

On another machine I could successfully run MLFlow with below versions so I tried to match those versions as well but it did not work. Running into the exact same error.

```
mlflow==2.8.1 
importlib-metadata==6.11.0
importlib-resources==6.1.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to downgrade Python from 3.12.1 to 3.11.5 and it solved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

this following settings worked for me:

1. python = 3.11.5
2. mlflow = 2.9.2
3. importlib-metadata

- importlib-metadata = 6.11.0 (pypi)
- importlib_metadata = 7.0.1 (conda-forge)

4. importlib_resources = 6.1.1 (conda-forge)